# Difference between logging in into salesforce sandbox with and without consuming wsdl?

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl, salesforce

I am very new to Salesforce and it's API.

I am having a sandbox org and with it I have [url](https://test.salesforce.com), username, password, security token and last but not the least partner.wsdl

My aim was to connect and retrieve/create data.

Technologies at hand was nodejs

So here is how I started.

I searched over the internet and came to know that I need to create a client, SOAP client in order to login, create the connection and use that connection to create and access the Leads data.So I followed [this](http://enreeco.blogspot.in/2013/11/nodejs-salesforce-soap-ws-how-to.html) sample where the wsdl was being consumed.

So I was able to connect

I was very happy on this success and then suddenly I wasn't able to identify/find a way where I can get the sObject.I looked hard for this but no luck. So posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742461/get-the-sobject-in-salesforce-in-nodejs-using-soap-node-module) on SO

Meanwhile I also looked for other node module and found [jsforce](https://jsforce.github.io/)

I used jsforce starting guide and created a client that was connecting to salesforce however without using the wsdl file.

Again I was happy, even more happy because I was having the sObject with me.

Now, what is the fundamental difference if I login using the local wsdl file and without wsdl file in the language of salesforce. Which one is the correct way of logging in?

Sorry if this question is not according to SO rules or if there is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of jsforce you mentioned.

In that lib we use REST API mostly and SOAP APIs are only used in some specific calls like login or metadata. Even in such calls we don't use WSDLs because there's no good lib to generate client modules from WSDL in JavaScript/Node.js area. Instead we wrote modules for each APIs which generate SOAP XML strings and parse the response XML.

It is enough because these API message schema are static and fiesible in the specific version, unlike SOAP API Enterprise WSDL differs in organizations. So we can hard code the client module directly w/o generate it from WSDL.

Comment: Thanks stomita for the answer.I guess I need to explore more on jsforce and SOAP .Thanks